# Django allauth custom registration view call from inside the application

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **django-allauth** for handling login and registration along with **django-rest-auth** to enable authentication via API using **django-allauth** library.

For handling the registration, I have written a custom view

```
class CustomRegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    permission_classes = register_permission_classes()

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_response_data(self, user):
        if allauth_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION == allauth_settings.EmailVerificationMethod.MANDATORY:
            return {"detail": _("Verification e-mail sent.")}

        return {"detail": _("Registration successful")}

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = self.perform_create(serializer)

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        return Response(self.get_response_data(user),
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        user = serializer.save(request=self.request)

        complete_signup(self.request, user, allauth_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION, None)
        return user
```

This handles all registration flow, verification, send signals, etc.

Now I want to create a user account manually from some other parts (views) of the application.

**Is it possible to use **CustomRegisterView** class to create an account?**

I just pass the fields required and the user is registered.

Comment: You can surely do that but it doesn't feel good. So, I'd probably move the logic (you have in `create` and `perform_create`) [to the serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) because it is [easy to reuse it](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects).